# Copy file to random directories?

Tags: bash

How can I copy a file to many random places on the hard drive? I was thinking something like

```
find ~ -type d -exec cp dat_boi.jpg {} \;
```

But that would copy to every directory, I just want to do like ~100 random ones anywhere on the disk.

Comment: Must these directories exist? What happens if you don't have write permission?

Comment: oh yeah they have to be directories that already exist. If write permissions are a problem I just assumed the script would fail for that one in particular and keep going.

Comment: First, do a `find` to get the list of possible directories and save the list to _lst.txt._ Then, randomly choose N items from _lst.txt_, and copy your file to these directories.

Comment: @jdt: Check out my answer below! Accept the same if it is helpful so that this post can be resolved

Answer (score 1):

A one-liner with `bash` `shuf` utility could do the trick.

```
/bin/cp -v dat_boi.jpg `find . -type d | shuf -n1`
```

This copies the `dat_boi.jpg` each time to a new folder as directed by `shuf` with argument as returning one random path `-n1`, `/bin/cp` with `-v` verbose flag  which is optional to see the target folder being copied and and `/bin/cp` is called over native `cp` which will avoid throwing a nasty error saying file exists instead of file-overwriting.

To see the copy being done to random folders.

```
$ find . -type d
.
./foo
./bar
./woo

$ /bin/cp -v dat_boi.jpg `find . -type d | shuf -n1`
`dat_boi.jpg' -> `./woo/dat_boi.jpg'
$ /bin/cp -v dat_boi.jpg `find . -type d | shuf -n1`
`dat_boi.jpg' -> `./bar/dat_boi.jpg'
$ /bin/cp -v dat_boi.jpg `find . -type d | shuf -n1`
`dat_boi.jpg' -> `./bar/dat_boi.jpg'
$ /bin/cp -v dat_boi.jpg `find . -type d | shuf -n1`
`dat_boi.jpg' -> `./woo/dat_boi.jpg'
$ /bin/cp -v dat_boi.jpg `find . -type d | shuf -n1`
`dat_boi.jpg' -> `./woo/dat_boi.jpg'
```

To suit your use-case, if you can run the command in a loop say, for 100 times, you can observe the randomity of the `shuf` working.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would do, but may not be super robust:

```
find . -type d | sort -R | head -n 5 | xargs -I {} cp myfile "{}"
```

In plain english: find directories from current directory, sort them randomly, select the five on top of this random list, and copy myfile to them.

```
$ ls
A  C  E  G  I  K  M       N  P  R  T  V  X  Z
B  D  F  H  J  L  myfile  O  Q  S  U  W  Y
$ find . -type d | sort -R | head -n 5 | xargs -I {} cp myfile "{}"
$ tree
.
├── A
├── B
├── C
├── D
├── E
├── F
├── G
├── H
├── I
│   └── myfile
├── J
├── K
├── L
│   └── myfile
├── M
│   └── myfile
├── myfile
├── N
├── O
├── P
├── Q
├── R
│   └── myfile
├── S
├── T
├── U
├── V
│   └── myfile
├── W
├── X
├── Y
└── Z
```

`tree` only allows to show the result.